# Build an Android Rom (Make Error 41)

Tags: java, git, android

I tried to build a custom Rom for Android 4.4.4. I use as base the Liquid Rom ([Github Link](https://github.com/LiquidSmooth))

Before I build the rom, I had insertes in the local_manifests some apps to add to the ROM and before I did repo sync I have removed some app.

Then I changed some parts of the settings application's source code to integrate some application in the settings munù. At the end of all I gave the command

```
./build-liquid.sh -o3 maguro.
```

After 277 minutes the process of building crashes giving me this error: 
    frameworks/opt/hardware/../../../device/samsung/tuna/cmhw/org/cyanogenmod/hardware/DisplayColorCalibration.java:70: reached end of file while parsing

```
} 


^ 1 error 


make: *[/home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/org.cyanogenmod.hardware_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Errore 41 
>make: ***Attesa per i processi non terminati.... Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sas5A.png)

[image]

The last line in english is: **Waiting for unfinished jobs**

I tried these errors on the internet and I found a topic where someone said that to solve the problem you could run the command

```
make showcommands
```

to check all the errors so I ran this command and it gave me this as a result:

```
Checking API: checkapi-last
( /home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/apicheck -JXmx1024m -J"classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/host/linux-x86/framework/doclava.jar:/home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jsilver.jar"  -hide 2 -hide 3 -hide 4 -hide 5 -hide 6 -hide 24 -hide 25 -hide 26 -hide 27 -error 7 -error 8 -error 9 -error 10 -error 11 -error 12 -error 13 -error 14 -error 15 -error 16 -error 17 -error 18   prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt  /home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt || (  cat build/core/apicheck_msg_last.txt ; exit 38 ) )
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:25635: error 9: Removed public method android.transition.TransitionManager.getDefaultTransition
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:25638: error 9: Removed public method android.transition.TransitionManager.setDefaultTransition

You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above

make: *** [/home/vincenzo/Sorgenti/Liquid/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkapi-last-timestamp] Errore 38
```

Then I search on internet also these errors and I found that to resolve the problem I have to do this command:

```
make update-api
```

However I have the same problems.

Then I reloaded again the sources, I reloaded again the "API" from the android sdk but I have always the same problem

Comment: SOLVED :D
I rewrote the file